# Textmate tab and de-tab selected block

Tags: macos, textmate

Recently switched to Textmate on Mac for coding.  On PC when ever I want to tab in or out a block of code I just highlight and press tab or shift+tab to move it in our out.  It's very useful when you are adding an extra loop or conditional statement to a block of code to keep everything tidy and neatly indented.

On Textmate however when I try this it just replaces my selected text with a tab.  So is there a way to do tab and de-tab lines of code in textmate?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Indent:       Alt+Tab

Un-Indent: Shift+Alt+Tab

Comment: :) http://manual.macromates.com/en/ can be a bit much to read through, but it's a good resource. For the most part, you'll learn TextMate as you use it.

Comment: Why doesn't Textmate support tab and shift+tab for indenting when multiple lines are selected, like most editors?

Comment: Answer: it's a general Mac shortcut and they don't want to override it in TextMate: http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2005-October/006391.html

Comment: Also, Textmate uses the tab key for nifty expansion functions.

Comment: This used to work for me on Lion, but it no longer works for me on Mavericks.  See Josh's answer below: cmd-] and cmd-[ will do the trick.

Comment: shift+alt+tab is harder to hit than ctrl+alt+del!!

Answer (score 9):

the hotkey is command-left bracket to move left and command-right bracket to move right
(the buttons next to 'p')

heres a link to more hotkeys and such
http://projects.serenity.de/textmate/tutorials/basics/

Comment: I can't find that anywhere in those docs. I find the documentation for textmate horrible in general.

Comment: Textmate calls it "Shift left" (= un-indent) and "Shift right" (= indent). You'll find it under these names in the doc and in Textmates' "Text" menu.

Comment: cmd+[ is easier to hit than shift+alt+tab ! (sadly on my custom remapped dvorak layout I need to press a shift as well... still a pretty decent option +1)

Comment: On a non-american keyboard layout the backet symbol may be hard to reach.

Answer (score 7):

You *can* use Shift+Tab to decrease indent; You just need to make and assign a macro. You can reuse this technique to accomplish a great many things.

1. Enter some text, and intend them, this is mostly for feedback.
2. Click the Record Macro Button

[image: Click the Record Macro Button]

3. Use <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> (aka; `Shift` + `Option` + `Tab`) to decrease the indentation.
4. Click the record button to stop recording the macro.
5. Use the `Edit` menu or <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to save your macro;

   [image: Edit -> Macros -> Save Macro]
6. Saving will prompt you to create a new bundle*, or add your macro to an existing bundle.
7. Add a `Key Equivalent` by clicking in the field and pressing  <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>
8. Your bundle-macro should look like the one below, simply Save and you're done! TextMate will now decrease indent on <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>

[image: Completed Macro]

*: (as noted by u/PatrickT) Sadly the create new bundle functionality has not yet been implemented, and you must choose to add to an existing bundle. You can still create a bundle via Bundles -> Edit Bundles then Command + N.

Comment: Seems promising! At step 2, you need to click on the red button to stop recording, before proceeding to step 3. At step 5, I chose "new bundle" at which point I got a message saying it was not supported. That's where I left it...

Comment: @PatrickT That is an unfortunate message, the bundle system is a WIP, but all you have to do is to choose an existing bundle. You can still create a bundle via Bundles -> Edit Bundles then Command + N.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! does it mean that I need to repeat this action for as many bundles as I use or is there a way to do it only once? (from my recollection the bundles are associated with a particular language, since I use about 10 or so, I was afraid I'd have to do that 10 times)

Comment: @PatrickT You only need one, as is this is effective everywhere, if you wanted to limit it you'd use the Scope Selector field.

Comment: Very kind of you to have taken me by the hand all the way! This worked great. I also added the TAB key for ``shiftRight`` in the same manner as above. I saved it under the R bundle, but I was indeed able to use it with a ``.py`` script. The steps will not be easy to remember, but I know I can always come back here for a step-by-step guide. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can **change the keybindings**, see [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180630072416/http://blog.macromates.com:80/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/)

Here is what I did:

- Install [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171003175126/http://www.cocoabits.com:80/KeyBindingsEditor/)
- Go to *File -> Open -> User Key Bindings*, this will create/edit `~/Libary/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`
- Add a binding, for the action enter **shiftRight:** (indent) manually (this is a TextMate specific action and not in the pre-populated actions list)
- Choose a shortcut, I used *cmd+alt+right*
- Do the same for the action **shiftLeft:** (un-indent, I used *cmd+alt+left*)
- Save and then restart TextMate

I used a shortcut with arrow keys as my right hand is already on the arrow keys when I am selecting multiple lines, so this is a good fit.

The reason why I did it was because I have a german keyboard and *alt+tab*/*alt+shift+tab* don't work for me since I am using [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/) for app-switching using these exact shortcuts.

**EDIT:** *cmd+alt+left/right* **don't work** when you have multiple tabs open, as they are used for navigate to next or previous tab in TextMate... seems this cannot be changed or overridden (I tried [Setting Shortcut Keys in Textmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417406/setting-shortcut-keys-in-textmate)). Looking for an alternative shortcut now.

Comment: I added \t and $\t to rightShift/leftShift, but unfortunately it only works when I have lines highlighted.  Is there anyway to make it work on the current line the cursor is on when no lines are highlighted?

Comment: The cocoabits website looks abandoned, is this the new place? https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/UI/KeyBindings/index.html

Comment: No, Unreal is a game :-) This might be a place to download that: https://de.freedownloadmanager.org/Mac-OS/KeyBindingsEditor-KOSTENLOS.html But I am sure there are other, newer solutions to edit the macOS keybindings.