# In textmate, how do I reverse indent a block of selected code?

Tags: python, textmate

I have a block of code selected, I want to un-indent this selected code.

On a pc, I would do a shift-tab and it would un-indent.

Comment: This isn't really a Python question.  It's really just Textmate.

Comment: But if he weren't using python, the indentation probably wouldn't matter. ;-)

Comment: To enable Shift+Tab in textmate, see my answer on the possible dupe of this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944400/textmate-tab-and-de-tab-selected-block/38134707#38134707

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>).

Omitting shift (or changing <kbd>]</kbd> to <kbd>[</kbd>) will indent instead of reverse-indent.

Comment: I think you meant Cmd+[ instead of Cmd+} as an alternative to un-indent the selected code.

Comment: Yeah, was just looking at the keys and brainfarted. :P Technically the same keys, but shift isn't involved for those. :)

Comment: Huh, didn't know about the `<kbd>` tag... neat. ^_^

Answer (score 4):

The following is from [*TextMate Power Editing for the Mac*](http://pragprog.com/titles/textmate/textmate) by James Edward Gray II.

---

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>

Decrease selection indent (works on current line when nothing is selected)

---

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>

Increase selection indent (works on current line when nothing is selected)

---

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Reindent selection based on current language grammar rules (works on current line when nothing is selected)